# How to set the sender when using AJAX to call MVC5 method

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been stuck on this for a few weeks, any help is very much appreciated!

I am building an MVC5 web application (This is my first C# & ASP.NET project). The model of this application is a web service. There is a page with a checkbox, and when clicked, this calls a bit of jQuery that uses AJAX to call a method in one of my controllers. This method calls a web service and updates a boolean value. This all seems to be working... my issue is that I need checkbox to be sent with the AJAX call, so that I can update a label on the page associated with the checkbox.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? (It seems rather hack-ish to me, using javascript to call my code). My question, though, is this: How can I pass the sender with an AJAX call?

CSHTML Page:

```
@Html.CheckBox("checkbox_subscribe", new{@id = "subscribeBox"})
@Html.Label("subscribebox", "Please notify me via email of any changes in lead times.")
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#subscribeBox").change(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("SubscribeClick", "Home")",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller Method:

```
public string SubscribeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String flag;
        if (sender == checked)
        {
            flag = "Y";
        }
        else
        {
            flag = "N";
        }
        websecurity.n_securitySoapClient proxy = new websecurity.n_securitySoapClient();
        String result = proxy.setsubscribeflag("11", flag, "leadtimes");
        if (result.StartsWith("<success>"))
        {
            if (flag == "Y") result = "Successfully subscribed for email.";
            else result = "Successfully unsubscribed from email.";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Just a side note: When I try casting the sender object to a CheckBox object type, I get the error: "InvalidCastException was unhandled by use code"

Comment: Code would helpful in determining your problem

Comment: @Pseudonym I just added all the relevant code

Comment: So you have the event firing correctly and the value being sent and received correctly? If the answer to both of these questions is yes, I don't see a problem with the way you are doing this. You could dig into mvc some more and do some model binding for a more complex object ... but for a simple checkbox, its not a big deal

Comment: `(object sender, EventArgs e)`? Is this MVC or webforms? If you want to pass data to the controller, then use the `data` option of  ajax - e.g. `data: { isSubscibed: true },` and make the method `public ActionResult SubscribeClick(bool isSubscibed)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did not even think about trying this, but it now successfully works! If you could write an answer with that information, I would be glad to accept it. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is client side code and has no concept of c# code such as `object sender, EventArgs e`. Change you method to accept a `boolean`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubscribeClick(bool isChecked)
{
  if(isChecked)
  {
    ....
  }
  else
  {
    ....
  }
  return Json(result, 
}
```

and then in the script, pass `true` or `false` based on the state of the checkbox

```
$("#subscribeBox").change(function (event) {
  var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("SubscribeClick", "Home")",
    data: { isChecked: isChecked },
    success: function (result) {
      alert(result);
    }
  });
});
```